# Heroku Project with rails and mongoLAB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I have a quick question. Iam new to rails and heroku too. I have recently downloaded a open source code from the following git repository git://github.com/barmstrong/ribbot.git. I am running rails with mongo db and have had the environment set up. Deciding to use heroku as my server solution I ahve downloaded the add on mongoLAB however when I try to run the code I get the following error. I can however run it smoothly on my local machine.

```
2012-04-16T22:51:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Add-on add mongolab:starter by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:51:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:51:21+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-04-16T22:53:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Add-on add shared-database:5mb by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Config add RAILS_ENV, LANG, PATH, RACK_ENV, GEM_PATH by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fe1b768 by *******@hotmail.com
2012-04-16T22:53:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-16T22:53:22+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-04-16T22:53:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 44817`
2012-04-16T22:54:06+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-16 22:54:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-04-16T22:54:06+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-16 22:54:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-04-16T22:54:06+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-16 22:54:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=44817
2012-04-16T22:54:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44817


2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 0)
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:54:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.124.140.154 at 2012-04-16 22:54:57 +0000
2012-04-16T22:54:58+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-16T22:54:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-04-16T22:54:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://herokuapp.com/forums
2012-04-16T22:54:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 114ms
2012-04-16T22:54:58+00:00 heroku[router]: GET impact-project.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=885ms status=302 bytes=93
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 1)
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 is down
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.124.140.154 at 2012-04-16 22:55:14 +0000
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://herokuapp.com/forums
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 11ms
2012-04-16T22:55:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET impact-project.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=528ms status=302 bytes=93
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 2)
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.124.140.154 at 2012-04-16 22:55:57 +0000
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://herokuapp.com/forums
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 4ms
2012-04-16T22:55:57+00:00 heroku[router]: GET impact-project.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=549ms status=302 bytes=93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have `localhost:11211` hard-coded somewhere in your Mongo driver configuration or have not specified to use the `MONGOLAB_URI` value from the environment.

See here for the MongoLab add-on docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab The section regarding using the value from the environment var is here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#connecting_your_heroku_application_to_your_mongodb_database and is driver-specific.

Hope that helps.